# Is it possible to swap two variables with only += and -= no other operators or variables?

Tags: c, swap

I want to swap two variables with only `+=` and `-=` operators and without temporary variables. I know the standard solutions like:

```
a = a+b;
b = a-b;
a = a-b;
```

and with `xor`:

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

but I cannot figure out how to do it with only `+=` and `-=`. Is it possible?

Comment: How about `b -= 2 * b`?

Comment: @Tom, again, `*` is not allowed

Comment: Who voted this question as "not constructive"? It's a very precise question, which *will* have a very precise answer (either a couple lines of code or "could not be done"). Its practical use might be debatable, but from a programming / math standpoint, it's valid *and* interesting.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible with the 4 operators `a+=b, a-=b, b+=a, b-=a`, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Agree with Tom. I'm not a mathematician so formal proof won't come from my side, but as far as I can see it can't be done. You're stuck with either a turned sign or a zero in one of the variables.

Comment: well maybe you are right. And you also can you `a+=a` and `a-=a`, the first one can be useful

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that there is a solution?

Comment: @Tom this is the question which was asked to my classmates on exam. I hope there is a solution :)

Comment: @medvedNick: Perhaps this is your prof's idea of a [Kobayashi Maru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru): How does the student handle a problem for which there *is* no solution? Will he find it within him to say "cannot be done" (with a bit of reasoning), or will he waste precious time on a wild goose chase?

Comment: @DevSolar that is possible. However, if I were a prof, I would ask questions without solution from maths, not from programming (the exam was for both), since in programming you can rather easily say if you solved or not the problem

Comment: @medvedNick: To the contrary - if this was a *combined* maths / programming exam, this makes a "Kobayashi Maru" all the more likely, because I would *expect* math students to be able to *formally prove* the futility of this assignment. I therefore assume this is the idea behind it.

Comment: @medvedNick Maybe the professor wanted to test, If given a problem in programming context will the student apply mathematical skills to check if it has a solution or just start assuming a soln and design a code for it.

Comment: I underestimated this quesiton at first glance. I have it such that they are swapped, but one of them has the wrong sign. :(

Comment: @Devolus That's the problem we're all having. Can you prove it can't be done?

Comment: @medvedNick Post it on math.stackexchange.com . Maybe mathematicians there can help you with a proof too

Comment: @SuvP thats a good idea,I'll try it

Comment: "I underestimated this quesiton at first glance." -- That's because you lead with the wrong end.

Comment: Now I have it exchanged with both signs inverted. But how to invert it?

Comment: @Devolus How did you manage that?

Comment: you were right, it was a math problem at all. Thanks to my classmates :) and to all who tried to help me

Comment: @Devolus If you can swap with 1 wrong sign and also swap with 2 wrong signs, then we can go {a,b} -> {-b,-a} -> {a,-b} -> {b,a}.

Comment: My above comment was a bit hasty. I can swap with one sign wrong and I can swap the sign of both.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

my classmates offer a nice solution:
the answer is `NO`

lets denote `a` as `(1 0)` and `b` as `(0 1)`

the matrix `A` is

```
1 0
0 1
```

`+=` and `-=` mean adding or subtracting lines to each other. That means the determinant either does not change its sign or it is equal to `0`. The end matrix is

```
0 1
1 0
```

with determinant equal to `-1`, so you can not get it

UPDATE:
you have these operations:

1. `a-=a`. One line becomes `0`, so `det=0`
2. `a+=a`. That means multiplying a line by `2`, so the `det A'= 2*det A`
3. `a+=b`. That means elementary transformation, which does not change the value of `det`
4. `a-=b`. The same thing as with `3.`

Then apply this proof for `b-=b`, `b+=b`, `b+=a`, `b-=a`. So the determinant does not change its sign or it is `0`

UPDATE 2:
as @Tom said here is the example of how to do that in C#: http://ideone.com/UzVLML. However, in C thats not correct: http://codepad.org/Rmhn9iqb. Can someone clarify the difference of   `b -= b += b` in C and C#?

Comment: could you  point us to a proof that adding or subtracting lines to each other does not change the sign of the determinant

Comment: @medvedNick: See, that's why I am a programmer, not a mathematician: I have *no* idea what you're talking about, but I take it at face value. ;-)

Comment: @MOHAMED updated answer with the proof, why the determinant will not change its sign to -1

Comment: @melvedNick `b -= b += b` is undefined behaviour in C because there are two assignments to `b` in the same expression, with no sequence point intervening. A sequence point is a marker for updates to occur, typically `;`, `&&`, `||`, the `?` in `bool ? true : false` articles, the point between evaluation of function parameters and transfer of control from caller to callee, a function returning, etc... Just search for "sequence points" in conjunction with "undefined behavior" and you'll see.

Answer (score 2):

Although OP has proved it's impossible, we can cheat in modern languages.

```
        a += b;
        b -= b += b; // Negates b in most languages, but not in C
        b += a;
        a -= b;
```

Comment: is not `a+=b` is exactly the same as `a=a+b`? I thought it has a return value in pure C. Just tested it too, and it does not work

Comment: `int a = 5;` `int b = a += 1;` Compilation error in C, but `b` is equal to `6` in C++, C# and Java.

Comment: we are talking about `int b = a += 1;`, right? http://codepad.org/vGBlsszR we can not change r-value, but we can use this value as input for other operators

Comment: It was working in the languages I tried, just not C, and I've never used C before so I don't really know what I'm doing. I'll delete this.

Comment: that worked, I'm confused a bit. Why it does not working in C? Whats is the difference? In my example in C there was no errors, but the output was different. Is it the order of assigning `b -= b += b;` differs?

Comment: I'm confused too. `a -= (a += a);` works in C++, C# and Java, but sets `a` to `0` in C and I am not sure why.

Comment: In C and C++03 `b -= b += b;` is undefined behavior because there are two writes without an intervening sequence point to the object referred to by `b`. In C++11 (which doesn't have sequence points) I believe that the assignment in an assignment expression is sequenced before the value computation of the assignment expression so I believe that it is valid.

Comment: @Tom... It is depends on compiler, Result differ on optimize compiler & normal compiler.

Comment: In any case, `b += b` does not have type `void`, it has the type of `b` and evaluates to the post-assignment value of `b`.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Thanks for your input. Yes I realised that and edited it out of the post.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: `b -= b += b` is still undefined in C++11. The evaluation of the left and right side of the `-=` operator are unsequenced relative to each other, which means that the modification of `b` (in the right side) and the value computation of `b` (in the left side) are unsequenced, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: @interjay: Oh sorry, I see what you're saying it's the fact that the previous value is _read_ that is unsequenced w.r.t. to the first write and that is what causes UB. Yes, good point.

Answer (score 0):

```
    a +=b;
    b -=a;
    b =-b;
    a -=b;
```